# How to compress SQL query more effectively using many OR conditions?

Tags: sql

Is there any good way to re-write this to something less duplicative/more efficient?

```
   Select
case when (
        A is null OR
        B is null OR
        C is null OR
        D is null
      ) then 1 else 0 end as flag_1...
```

Comment: which database are you using, basically only mysql has a good and simple answer, the rest not so much

Comment: @nbk I am using redshift sql

Comment: i added a version for redshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write,

IN YSQL you can chekc with CONCAT , if one is nNULL it return NULL

```
Select
case when (
        CONCAT(A,B,C,D) IS NULL
      ) then 1 else 0 end as flag_1...
```

In REDSHIFT you have a similar syntax. The convesion is need if the columns are not varchar

```
Select
case when (
   A::varchar||B::varchar||C::varchar||D::varchar is null
      ) then 1 else 0 end as flag_1...
```

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped my question. Instead of "AND" I meant "OR". Let me know if that changes your answer. Thanks so much

Comment: then check if it iS NOT NULL

Comment: is this for AND or OR boolean?